# Convergence of $\;\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{(-n)^n}\;$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Does the following series converge?
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{(-n)^n}$$
I've tried both the root- and the ratiotest, where the resulting sequence seems to always converge to $1$. I've also tried the Leibniz test where:
$$\left|\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{(-n)^n}\right| \;=\; \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n \;\cdot\; \frac{1}{n+1} \; \longrightarrow\; e\cdot0\;=\; 0$$
but am unable to show that the absolute value of the sequence is also decreasing. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$ \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = \frac{(n+2)^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n-1}} = \frac{(n+2)^n n^n}{(n+1)^{2n}} = \left(\frac{n^2+2n}{n^2+2n+1}\right)^n < 1$$
so $|a_{n+1}|<|a_n|$ and you can use the Leibniz test.

Comment: But that's not enough, right? We need $\;\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < q < 1\;$ for the test to be conclusive. Otherwise, $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ would also be convergent as $\frac{n}{n+1}<1$

Comment: Oh right, I'm sorry; I thought you were referring to the ratiotest. This actually solves the problem then; I guess I didn't make that connection when evaluating the fraction, so thank you!

Comment: A good reason that Adam should have included some words in this answer, not merely formulas.

Comment: That's why I'm "scared" of answering simple questions...

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=(n+1)^{n-1}n^{-n}$ be the absolute value of the term; then, for $n>1$, $$a_n/a_{n-1}=(n+1)^{n-1}n^{-n}n^{-n+2}(n-1)^{n-1}=(1-n^{-2})^{n-1}<1.$$

Comment: I wasn't confusing tests.  It had appeared that you had misapplied the ratio test.  Your solution wasn't explicitly stating your thoughts.  But after your comment, I understand what you were doing now.

Comment: @MarkViola: Well, ok - both answers follow *the end of the question* with a surprising silence ;)